# Python CSV Splitting Full Name String into First and Last Name

Tags: python

I have a .csv that has a full name column with around 50 first and last names. I would like to use Python to import the .csv and loop thru and split the full name into first and last name columns into a new .csv file. I am not sure how to go about this with Python.

Comment: You want to look into the csv module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html rest of the string processing is going to depend on your specific requirements.

Comment: I am looking to split the strings by the blank space, so the full name of John Doe would go into the new csv as first name John last name Doe.

Comment: `text.split()` is what you need.

Comment: Sounds like you understand and have clearly defined your problem. What have you tried so far? I've upvoted you, but please try opening a CSV file and see how far you can get. Update your question if you get stuck. Good luck!

Comment: Try not to fall for the [Fallhoods Programmer's Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code that will help you, you can use the csv module as others have suggested in the comments

```
import csv

with open('old.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    newcsvdict = {"first name": [], "last name": []}
    for row in reader:
        first = row[0].split()[0]
        last = row[0].split()[1]
        newcsvdict["first name"].append(first)
        newcsvdict["last name"].append(last)

with open('new.csv', 'wb') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, newcsvdict.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(newcsvdict)
```